# How to select rows between two index

Tags: mysql

we can select row from index i to j with below code in Sql server.how to do it in mysql?

```
select * from 
  (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FieldName asc) as row,
  * from TableName) 
WHERE row between STARTINDEX AND ENDINDEX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure did I understand question totally correct, because I'm not super-familiar with SQL: You want to order results by FieldName and select some portion of results based on row numbers you created. I would write that in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY FieldName ASC
LIMIT STARTINDEX-1, ENDINDEX-STARTINDEX
```

In MySQL LIMIT index starts from zero (in your SQL-code from 1) and other number in LIMIT clause is number of records you are willing to get

EDIT: My result was missing row number. In case you want row number in your result, it would go like this:

```
SET @num = STARTINDEX-1;
SELECT @NUM := (@NUM + 1) AS row, TableName.*
FROM TableName
ORDER BY FieldName ASC
LIMIT STARTINDEX-1, ENDINDEX-STARTINDEX
```

STARTINDEX is same as first row's number because SELECT will add one to @NUM even at the first time